# How do I make tab open my custom selector in the form of my angular application?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angularjs

I have a form with input components and my custom selector components and I want to make it so that when i tab through the form, the custom NgbDropdown selectors open. But I want to make these changes to my custom selector component, not the form component.

This is what I have so far:

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.addEventListener('focusin', () => {
      if (!this.myDrop.isOpen()) {
        this.myDrop.open();
      }
    });
  }
```

This opens the selector component successfully as I tab through the form, but when i want to click on the selector to open and close it, it opens and closes the selector component super quick. It only works if i hold the click on the selector component--that opens it as long as I hold. How do I change this so it applies to all the selector components in the application?